# How to prevent Wysiwyg-Editor from adding Elements while toggling Show/Hide?

Tags: javascript, magento, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have following problem regarding magento 1.9 TinyMCE wysiwyg editor in the backend.
Upon toggling the editor whilst editing the product description of a product, the  element is being extended.

```
<video class="margin-top-20 width100" src="/media/wysiwyg/pds/21600/video.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
```

gets extended to

```
<video width="320" height="240" class="margin-top-20 width100" src="/media/wysiwyg/pds/21600/video.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"><object width="320" height="240" data="https://homepage.com/js/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="https://homepage.com/js/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="url=/media/wysiwyg/pds/21600/video.mp4&amp;poster=/media/" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="true" /></object></video>
```

After reading this article by Alan Storm https://alanstorm.com/magento_html5_tinymce/
I tried to extend the settings by this:

extended_valid_elements :

```
'iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder|allowTransparency|allowfullscreen],style,script,'+'video[class|src|autoplay|loop]',
```

Unfortunately this did not help. Could someone provide any help regarding this issue?

Comment: I guess it's impossible to prevent that extra `<object>` element, that looks like a part of TinyMCE's core functionality to me. Probably install another editor?

Comment: Installing an extension for the tinymce (https://github.com/meanbee/Meanbee_Tinymce5) did not work. Is there any other solution?